# Creating table with Apache Spark using delta format got stuck

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I wanna create a table using a delta location but my process got stuck.

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE bronze_table USING DELTA LOCATION 'dbfs:/mnt/poc-databricks-folder/bronze/delta'")
```

> ...Running command

The process does not finished, I ran that 24 hours ago and it is still in "Running command". I have a streaming job running that stores delta format in a path without problems.

[image]

I can see the spark catalog.
[image]

My problem is that the process for creating a table using the previous path got stuck, and I would like to know the reason. I tried restarting the cluster, remove all from the folder, drop databases, drop tables, but I have the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you were to create the batch table prior to running the stream?